# Swift 3 disable Control-Center and statusbar swipe

Tags: swift3, notifications, controls

I will build an app. The User can leave the App only by click in the end Button or with the Homebutton.

Now of i swipe down the statusbar is shown. Same with swipe Up from the Button the Control Center comes Up.
Can i disable this? In xcode i checked hide statusbar and requires fullscreen.
The statusbar is hidden.

I removed the gestureRecognizers:
In viewDidLoad:

```
Self.view.gestureRecognizers?.forEach(View.removeGestureRecognizer)
```

Or cant i disable the swipe Up/swipe down for controlCenter,notificationscreen

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sadly you can't, it's just to allow the users to keep those features accessible and not having the app to block their phone.

Comment: Oh really? In all the fullscreen games the Control-Center ist Not disable? Oh okay thats Bad:( but thanks

Comment: This is possible in Android I think, I saw some apps truly blocking everything but the app.

Comment: addition to my answer, you might be able to force someone to use a single app by using parenting mode, you can read more here: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202612

Comment: Thats it! Thanks